# How to efficiently test code that loads a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, database, jupyter-notebook, airflow

I'm writing a Python script to load, filter, and transform a large dataset using pandas. Iteratively changing and testing the script is very slow due to the load time of the dataset: loading the parquet files into memory takes 45 minutes while the transformation takes 5 minutes.

Is there a tool or development workflow that will let me test changes I make to the transformation without having to reload the dataset every time?

Here are some options I'm considering:

- *Develop in a jupyter-notebook:* I use notebooks for prototyping and scratch work, but I find myself making mistakes or accidentally making my code un-reproducible when I develop in them. I'd like a solution that doesn't rely on a notebook if possible, as reproducibility is a priority.
- *Use Apache Airflow (or a similar tool):* I know Airflow lets you define specific steps in a data pipeline that flow into one another, so I could break my script into separate "load" and "transform" steps. Is there a way to use Airflow to "freeze" the results of the load step in memory and iteratively run variations on the transformation step that follows?
- *Store the dataset in a proper Database on the cloud:* I don't know much about databases, and I'm not sure how to evaluate if this would be more efficient. I imagine there is zero load time to interact with a remote database (because it's already loaded into memory on the remote machine), but there would likely be a delay in transmitting the results of each query from the remote database to my local machine?

Thanks in advance for your advice on this open ended question.

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of work like that, I'll break it up into intermediate steps and pickle the results. I'll check if the pickle file exists before running the data load or transformation.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Only problem is there's manual/cognitive load in remembering when the code before the pickle changes and the pickle needs to be deleted. I wonder if there is a tool for automating that? Or if building that tool would be possible?

Comment: Depending on your access patterns, you can write a class that caches the data. In my own work I have a class that takes a query converts the query to an MD5 hash. It queries the data write a cache file that [MD5Hash].pkl. And the class itself takes care of reading from the pkl file or back from Hive/SQL/etc if the pkl file doesn't exist.